# How to set selected values in bootstrap selectepicker multiple with AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap selectpicker and I cant set values to be selected. I have try to set the model name in his values of array, but it doesn't work sadly.

```
<select
    class="form-control"
    name="groupCustomer"
    title='Choose'
    id="tags" multiple data-multiple-separator=" " data-max-options="3"
    ng-model="moreDetailsData.groupCustomer">

    <option ng-repeat="grp in groupCustomer" value="{{grp.id}}" data-content="<span class='label ' style='background:{{grp.group_color}}'>{{grp.group_name}}</span>">

            </option>
 </select>
```

Call To the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#tags').selectpicker('val','[1,2]');
    }); 
</script>
```

Angular:

```
$scope.groupCustomer = [
{"id" : 1,"name" : "group 1"},
 { "id" : 2, "name" : "group 2"},
 {"id" : 3,"name" : "group 3" },
 {"id" : 4,"name" : "group 4" }]

$scope.moreDetailsData.groupCustomer = [1,2,3];
```

What could I do to get it fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
 $timeout(function () {          
            $('#tags').selectpicker();
$('#tags').selectpicker('val',$scope.moreDetailsData.groupCustomer).trigger("change"); 
        });
```

See this link : https://jsfiddle.net/n57ekstu/18/

Comment: getting this error `e.stopPropagation is not a function`

Comment: can you create fiddler so i can help you accurately.

Comment: I created a fidlle but something doesn't work well [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/n57ekstu/12/) he doesn't show me the list, maby i'm missing something